# Powershell Release file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I understand that Powershell does not release a file until the script has exited. In my scripting I am writing to a new file as this:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("E:\Outline\newLocations.xml", $locationsContent)
```

How can I release this file so I can read later in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WriteAllText` method does not lock the file. Here's an example of creating a new text file, writing to it using that method, then reading from it, then deleting it. You can test this as well by creating a file, writing to it, then PowerShell still open try deleting it from Windows Explorer. Classes will have generally have a `Dispose` method, if you need to release the instance.

```
New-Item "C:\temp\newLocations.txt" -ItemType File

Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/11/2017  12:16 PM              0 newLocations.txt

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\temp\newLocations.txt", "test")

Get-Content "C:\temp\newLocations.txt"
test

Remove-Item "C:\temp\newLocations.txt"

get-item "C:\temp\newLocations.txt"
get-item : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\newLocations.txt' because it does not exist.
```